# Create a file in DataLake and make it expire after 2 minutes

Tags: azure-data-lake, data-lake

I am using Data Lake Gen 1 and i would like to create a file and set the expiration time to be 2 minutes after creation.

I am using this method:

```
public virtual System.Threading.Tasks.Task SetExpiryTimeAsync (string path, Microsoft.Azure.DataLake.Store.ExpiryOption eopt, long expiryTime, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancelToken = null);
```

like this:

```
await client.SetExpiryTimeAsync(fileDestinationPath, ExpiryOption.RelativeToNow, _adlsFileExpirationInMinutes);
```

I could not find how the parameter **long expiryTime** works. In MSDN it says *"It's interpretation depends on what ExpiryOption user passes"*.

What I do not understand is that this value is a long: what does it represents: seconds, ticks, hours...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It represents `milliseconds`, you can find this information from the sync method `SetExpiryTime`. The following is the screenshot I get from the sdk via visual studio:

[image]

A little more information, from the source code of Azure Data lake [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-data-lake-store-net/blob/master/AdlsDotNetSDK/ADLSClient.cs#L992), the sync-mothed `SetExpiryTime` actually does nothing but just calls the async-method `SetExpiryTimeAsync` inside, so both of them have the same parameter definition:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

From experiments: it is in milliseconds for relative `ExpliryOption` values and Unix UTC timestamp in milliseconds for `ExpiryOption.Absolute`.

If you need to convert DateTime to Unix timestamp - you can use:

```cs
(long)DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1)).TotalSeconds * 1000
```